# JHipster - get selected language in the backend

Tags: angular, spring-boot, jhipster

I want to do a blog application with i18n text in the database.

How can I get in the backend the frontend selected language?

Does JHipster provides any way to access to the selected language in the backend?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ok, I got it. I'll try to explain it if it would be useful for someone.

In JHipster's frontend the language is managed by JhiLanguageService.

Inject this in the constructor of a component where you want to use i18n in the backend:

```
 private languageService: JhiLanguageService
```

and in the query call add the following parameter:

```
language: this.languageService.currentLang
```

for example:

```
   this.moviesService.query({
        language: this.languageService.currentLang
    })
```

Then in the backend, add the Locale as a parameter in the RestController where you need it and there you have the front-end selected language thanks to the LocaleConfiguration class.

Sweet

Comment: Unfortunately this method does not work anymore.

Answer (score 0):

You can keep the selected language in a variable and send it in the http request to backened.

Comment: I'm sorry, I did not explain myself well. What I want to know is if JHipster offers any way to access to the selected language in the backend, or if I have to do it by myself.