# How to get the selected language in the backend from JHipster

Tags: angular, spring-boot, jhipster

What is the preferred way to get the selected language in the backend from a JHipster app?

I've found [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51012437/jhipster-get-selected-language-in-the-backend), but the described method does not work anymore, because the Language Service does not exist.

Another approach I tried was the `LocaleConfiguration` class, which uses a cookie to get the language. But I had to find out, that the cookie is not being set. So this class is useless.

Furthermore no requests are being sent to the backend if the language changes. The only thing happening is that the language is being stored in a `SessionStorageService`.

What is the preferred way to get the language in the backend?
Should I manually set the cookie and use the class described above or access the session storage somehow?
Should I send a request every time the language is changed and store that in the DB (jhipster user entity has a language column)?
Or should I do something different?

Comment: You should send a request every time the language is changed and store that in the DB

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think I will try to handle everything locale specific in the frontend, so I don't have to send requests at all.

Comment: OK but then locale change won't be permanent. Sending a request is simpler and better

Comment: I've added an answer describing my current solution to this. This ist not exactly the answer to the question, but it works for me.

Answer (score 0):

The use case for me was to add translations to some entity attributes, so this attributes are localized.

Here is an example:

```
entity MyEntity {
    name String unique required
    // other fields
}

entity MyEntityTranslation {
    localizedName String
    language Language
}

relationship OneToMany {
    MyEntity{translation} to MyEntityTranslation{myEntity(name) required}
}
```

My solution to this is maybe not the best, but works for me, because the are only a couple languages involved.

I have activated eager fetching for the translation table so all translations are always loaded. Then I added all translations to the base entity view, only showing the one with the current language. This way every language switch just showing and hiding the appropriate fields without the need to communicate to the backend.

If all fields are properly filled the save button sends the main entity together with the translations to the backend persisting everything in one transaction (cascade all).